# Make a DIV full screen and act like position relative

Tags: css, css-position

I want a div element to fill the full screen.  So I have the following items:

```
<div style="background:black;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;"></div>
<div>Hello</div>
<div>World</div>
```

The problem I'm having is that the Hello World divs appear on top of the full screen div.  I want the Hello World divs to appear after the full screen div, so that you have to scroll to it.

Essentially, I want the full screen div to act like it's relatively positioned.  I don't want to use javascript to hard code the starting positions of the Hello World div.

Is there an easy way to achieve what I want with CSS only?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the first `<div>` to be full-screen you simply need to take advantage of the `vh` length units, rather than positioning absolutely:

```css
/* Removing padding and margin from
   the specified elements: */
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-width: 0;
}
/* a <div> is already 100% wide,
   so we specify only the height,
   and ensure that any lengths
   are calculated to include
   border-width, padding and margin
   using the box-sizing property: */
.fullpage {
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* purely so that there is something
   to see easily, irrelevant to the
   demo: */
div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f90;
}
div {
  min-height: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullpage"></div>
<div>Hello</div>
<div>World</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qnbvaape/).

References:

- [Viewport-relative length units](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths).

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
<div style="background:black; height:100vh;"></div>
<div>Hello</div>
<div>World</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
```

no need for absolute top left right bottom;